# Enable CORS in vespa

Tags: vespa

How to enable CORS in vespa? I want to deploy my API's to swagger UI but due to CORS disbled in vespa, I am unable to do this. Is there any way to enable CORS in vespa or How should I use API's in swagger to use it? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Vespa does not come with built-in CORS support. You'll have to implement the CORS logic yourself as JDisc security filters ([http-server-and-filters.html](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/jdisc/http-server-and-filters.html), [services-http.html#filter](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/services-http.html#filter)).

The [Vespa source code](https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/tree/master/jdisc-security-filters/src/main/java/com/yahoo/jdisc/http/filter/security/cors) contains a set of CORS filters that can be used as inspiration.
You can technically use them, but they are not public API and can be changed/removed in the future.

You will need two filters:

- A request filter handling CORS preflight HTTP requests
- A response filter that appends CORS headers to HTTP responses

Note that the response filters are not invoked if a request filter returns a response. Any other JDisc filters in your application must therefore include the CORS headers when they return a response.

See [http-server-and-filters.html#set-up-filter-chains](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/jdisc/http-server-and-filters.html#set-up-filter-chains) on how to configure request/response filter chains.

Comment: I am creating my custom RequestFilter and ResponseFilter. Where should I place these classes?Where should I create directory components?

Comment: See https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/jdisc/http-server-and-filters.html

Comment: I am not able to find where should I create components directory using above link. I have created components directory in application package where we keeps search and searchDefitions directories. Now I components directory, Should I create src/main/java/com/yahoo/demo/CustomRequestFilter or direct keep CustomRequestFilter class? And according to the doc, where should I create artifact id filter-bundle?

Comment: The Java components can be placed in any Java package inside a bundle. You'll find examples on how to create a bundle with custom components in the vespa-engine/sample-apps repository (e.g https://github.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps/tree/master/http-api-using-request-handlers-and-processors).